# HTML : Unable to execute code in <script> block, but able to run in console

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my code :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            document.getElementById("id").onclick = function(){
                alert();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <label id="id">A label</label>
    </body>
</html>
```

It is simple, but I can't get it to work.

When I copied the code inside `<script>` and ran it at console, it worked perfectly.

Comment: The code is run when the script tag appears on the page and the body won't be loaded if you place it in the head. Either place inside body after your content or add some code to wait before the DOM is loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The onclick event isn't firing because the element doesn't exist at the time you bind the click event (DOM isn't loaded yet).

To fix this you can put the script before you close the body tag (1)
or wrap your code in a DOM loaded event (2).

1)

```
<html>
    <head>            
    </head>
    <body>
        <label id="id">A label</label>
        <script>
            document.getElementById("id").onclick = function(){
                alert();
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

2)

```
window.onload = function () {
   document.getElementById("id").onclick = function(){
      alert();
   }
}
```